# Electron/Node.js: extract file from REST response and save to local disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, electron, response

I am building an Electron app which receives a `tar.gz`-file from a REST request, using `electron.net.request`, and would like to save the file to the local disk when the response data is processed:

```
myRequest.on('response', (response) => {
          response.on('error', (error) => {...})

          response.on('data', (chunk) => {
             //the following produces a file at targetPath but it doesn't contain anything
             fs.writeFile("/some_dir/myFile.tar.gz", chunk, (err) => {...})
          })
         })
```

When I try to apply `fs.writeFile` to the raw data being returned by `myRequest`, a file is written at the correct path, but it does not contain anything. I can verify in a browser that the same REST-request returns a valid gzipped `tar`, which I can unpack.
How can I retrieve the file in Electron (or Node.js) on processing the response?

Comment: Is there more than one chunk?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the hint, the examples I have seen so far just operate on this chunk, including the example at electronjs.org/docs/api/net.

Comment: Okay, but I'm asking if there are multiple chunks in *your* case, because if so, you'll need to restructure this quite a bit.

Comment: How can I best check that?

Comment: Put a console.log in the data handler? A breakpoint?

Comment: I can see in my log that apparently the ```response.on('data', (chunk)=>{...})``` callback is called several times - is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that means there's more than one `data` event (multiple chunks).

Comment: Could you maybe give me some hints or references on how to deal with that?

Comment: The docs for `writeFile` explicitly state that (a) the file will be overwritten by default, and (b) writing to the same file before waiting for the callback is bad. The docs suggest using `writeStream` (or something like that; on different machine now). So you'd want to write continuously to an output stream, and close it when there's no more data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it now works with a stream, I just did not find anything in the documentation of electron's ClientRequest on how to tell that all data has been received -- any idea?

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/net, https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request#event-finish

Comment: Great, the line ```response.on('end', ()=>{...})``` finally did the trick -- I had only found the ```event-finish``` thing which refers to the request only and leads to premature closing of the stream. Thank you so much for your help! If you'd bother to combine your hints (multiple calls to callback-> using stream, close stream in ```response.on('end', ...)```) into an answer, I'd happily accept&upvote it...